# How do I copy a range from an active sheet without specifying sheet name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that will work as a blank form and I will duplicate and rename for each client. I need certain dates in a range to be copied and pasted (values only) to one calendar sheet in order to see all client dates in one place. I recorded a macro and it works but I cannot determine how to make it the active sheet range (being the duplicated Blank and renamed for client) and not the "Blank" sheet range. Script below:

```
function AddCalendarBlank() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-2, -2);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-6, -4, 5, 3).activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(currentCell);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calendar"); 
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Blank!A59:C63').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

Comment: Thank you. I have that but on the second to last line you can see when it goes to paste to the calendar sheet it references the "Blank" sheet instead of the original active sheet range. Do you know how I can correct that?

Comment: `sheet.getRange('A59:C63').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);`

Comment: I really appreciate your help! The only issue when I do this is nothing pastes. It is empty. I am thinking it is because I am having the macro go to the next open row so it is activating last row + 1. I'm just at a loss on how to get it to work.

Comment: I don't really know what the range is supposed to be I was just copying that line and replacing spreadsheet with sheet.  So you may have to figure it out yourself.  Put your thinking cap on.